# should inheritance work for static variable

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm not sure this is right question to be asked, may be inheritance works in instances only.

I have provided the code below where we are counting the how many X instances is been created using python descriptor based approach, where X is modifying the inherited  static variable.

```py
class X:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        owner.howManyX.append(name)


class Base:
    howManyX = []


class A(Base):
    a1 = X()
    a2 = X()
        

class B(Base):
    b1 = X()
    b2 = X()


print(id(A.howManyX), A.howManyX )
print(id(B.howManyX), B.howManyX)
print(id(Base.howManyX), Base.howManyX)
```

Since both **A** and **B** class should have inherited **Base** class `howManyX`. But  output is bit unexpected as show below variable seem to be same.

```
139852096097856 ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2']
139852096097856 ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2']
139852096097856 ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* inheritance. `A` and `B` are inheriting *the same attribute* from `Base` and mutating the object it refers to.

You want the opposite of inheritance, you want to *override* `howManyX = []` in each of the subclasses, so each class gets it's *own attribute* referring to a distinct object.

Notice, you get *the exact same behavior* using an instance:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     bar = []
...
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> foo1.bar.append('baz')
>>> foo2.bar.append('bing')
>>> Foo.bar is foo1.bar is foo2.bar
True
>>> Foo.bar, foo1.bar, foo2.bar
(['baz', 'bing'], ['baz', 'bing'], ['baz', 'bing'])
```

All inheritance means in Python is when you look up some attribute, `some_obj.some_attribute`, that you lookup that attribute in the namespaces you inherit. So if `.some_attribute` is looked up in `some_obj`, and it isn't found, then, the class namespace, and all the classes in the method resolution order are consulted (in order).

If `some_obj` is itself a class, you skip any instance lookup, and head straight for the class namespace and the namespaces in the method resolution order.

Comment: can we make `howManyX` be unique without overriding?

Comment: @rho no, how else could you?

Comment: ok i got it static variable are shared and instance variable are unique

Comment: @rho instance variables belong to the instance namespace, *class variables* (the conventional terminology in python) belong *to the class namespace*.

Comment: @rho you could check if `owner.__dict__` has `"howManyX"` and initialize it in the descriptor `__set_name__`, but I think that's a bad idea. Explicit is better than implicit.